# GCC: any way to disable -fstack-usage for a specific function?

Tags: gcc, pragma

I bet there is something like #pragma .. "-fno-stack-usage" or something. Basically what I get is an error like this:

```
error: stack usage computation not supported for this target [-Werror]
```

I don't want to disable -fstack-usage globally. I have also tried to do #pragma GCC diagnostics ignored "-Werror" with no effect.

Comment: Would putting the function in its own compilation unit be an acceptable workaround?

Comment: That would go into the category of "doing stupid hacks because gcc wouldn't let you get it right" (before I start digging into gcc source to see what the issue is I would rather ask if there is a possible pragma workaround)

Comment: My latest addition to the "stupid hacks" category is to conditionally add -Werror if STACK_USAGE make variable is not set to one and to add -fstack-usage if it is. So I can do make STACK_USAGE=1 to get stack usage. Not ideal but best so far.

Comment: Does the function in question have any inline asm?

Comment: Yes. That is the root of the problem. (I can not remove the asm because it is task switching code).

Comment: Hmm. This gave me an idea. I'll see if I can just move all asm into .S files.

Comment: Have you tried using a function attribute in order to disable the optimisation just for a specific function? For instance: void function(int i) __attribute__((optimize("-fno-stack-usage")));

Comment: Interesting idea. However -fstack-usage does not behave like other options and does not seem to have -fno-stack-usage (unrecognized command line option '-fno-stack-usage').

Comment: @Martin: indeed. I have another idea though, you can give it a try:
1. #pragma GCC push_options
2. #pragma GCC optimize("the options you want without fstack-usage")
3. your function
4. #pragma GCC pop_options

Comment: @Martin : any luck with my latest suggestion?